# Visual Studio C# blocks not formatting normally on "enter"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, formatting, settings

Note that `|` represents my cursor

When I type in

```
public void test()|
```

and then hit the `{` in the same row, like this:

```
public void test(){|
```

a `}` is inserted after.

Now I have this:

```
public void test(){|}
```

Now I click Enter to go to the next row, and I expect the `{` to go one line below, like this:

```
public void test()
{
    |
}
```

but this is what I get:

```
public void test(){
    |}
```

How do I get the result I want?

Answer (score 1):

You go to `Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# > Code Style > Formating > New Lines` and customize the formatting as you like it.

In your case the option "Place open brace on new line for ..." is important.

EDIT: Also if you want to have the closing brace indented like in your example then you can do this under `Indentation`

Comment: strangely that doesn't help. i tried that, but nothing happens. could the settings fil be corrupted or something of that nature?

Comment: @Monset hm, maybe you have any extensions overriding the set formatting?